# What is this contraption?

Tags: panorama, gopro, 360-panorama

[This photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVE3x.jpg) has appeared on my news feed. What interests me is this (sorry it's blurred, it wasn't the focal point of the image!):

[image: camera contraption]

It looks to me like 6 (assuming it's a cube) of GoPro cameras, and I can only assume that somehow these are stitched together into a 360 degree photo/video later on. Can anyone provide any more details?

Comment: Your question itself seems to pretty much sum it up.  It's some kind of specialty mount for GoPros to get a 360 degree sphere of shots.  Probably takes care of synchronizing capture too.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I was kind of looking for confirmation! I was in some doubt because all it seems to be recording is the press waiting for Princess Catherine to leave with her baby, so it's not there to record her really...

Comment: I can't think of anything else it could be with that kind of configuration.  It may be that someone just built it and is trying it out there or that they have it in their kit, so they just bring it.  Novelty can make a difference in something that lots of people are covering.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about videography. Yes you can use a GoPro for photos but not a mount like that. Try this on avp.stackecchange.com

Comment: I think it is a Borg cube :-|

Comment: I think it actually _is_ used for still panoramas, which are on topic.

Comment: Related projects: [Bublcam](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/bublcam/bublcam-360o-camera-technology-for-everyone), [Panono](http://www.indiegogo.com/projects/panono-panoramic-ball-camera)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is http://www.lewiswhyld.com/royal-baby-arrives/ GoPro rig, somewhat similar to the http://freedom360.us rig. Lewis is a photo journalist based in the UK, and his rig appears to be a one-off, where the F360 is actually in production.

Comment: Wonderful! I never thought I'd actually get to see the results of the panorama, so thanks for finding/sharing that. The other 360 panoramas on his site are equally as impressive.

Comment: There seem to be a photographer or two present (in the shot).  Is it bad I found checking out all the photographer's gear by far the most interesting thing in the photo?

Comment: I just learned it's not the rig from Lewis Whyld, but a rig from AFP... it could be a F360, but the bokeh doesn't help making a positive ID. I am sure it is gopro based.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a [Freedom360](http://freedom360.us/shop/freedom360/) mount for recording "spherical video."

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the same thing, but I think your conclusion is basically correct.  Here is one version of such devices.

http://www.trendhunter.com/trends/360degree-view-camera-mount

The one I found looks like it allows multiple GoPro's to be linked together in a configurable fashion so that you can capture a variety of different specialty shots, whether it be 360 or some type of bullet time like effect or even just a basic panoramic.